# How to upload local files to AWS Elastic File System (EFS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

I'd like to add files to my efs using command line but can't see any info online. I've mounted my EFS to an EC2 instance. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "upload local files to EFS"? Amazon EFS is a disk storage system that can be attached to Amazon EC2 instances. Are you wanting to upload files from a different computer to that EC2 instance, such that the EC2 instance will store the files on the EFS filesystem?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes, upload files to ec2 instance that will store to the efs

Comment: i have tried using the scp command but permission is denied

Answer (score 0):

try using the scp command
you'll just need your pem and the public ID of your EC2

tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@dearsikandarkhan/files-copying-between-aws-ec2-and-local-d07ed205eefa)

Answer (score 0):

I deployed this solution via CloudFormation in AWS console
https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/simple-file-manager-for-amazon-efs/
[image]

You will need to provide - Stack name and AdminEmail. Don't put a too long name for stack name, otherwise one nested stack deployment will fail.

[image]
Wait until you see the status "CREATE_COMPLETE" for all stacks - main and nested.
Open tab Outputs in the main stack and click the link. This link will direct you to the webpage where you need to log in with the previously provided email and temporary login you will receive on it.

Then click on "false" and wait until a new nested stack will be created.
[image]

Create directory and upload file.
[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTqWQy8k5i0